# I don't understand what I'm doing wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x

My Task:

The groups_per_user function receives a dictionary, which contains group names with the list of users. Users can belong to multiple groups. Fill in the blanks to return a dictionary with the users as keys and a list of their groups as values.

My answer:

```
def groups_per_user(group_dictionary):
    user_groups = {}
    for groups, user in group_dictionary.items():
        for users in user:
            if users in user_groups:
                user_groups[users].append(groups)
            else:
                user_groups[users] = groups


    return(user_groups)

print(groups_per_user({"local": ["admin", "userA"],
        "public":  ["admin", "userB"],
        "administrator": ["admin"] }))
```

```
Error on line 17:
    "administrator": ["admin"] }))Error on line 8:
    user_groups[users].append(groups)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Comment: Going forward, please try to think of a more descriptive title. Every single question on this site is from someone who needs help with code; your title should help us decide if the problem you are having is one we are interested in and may have the competence to help with.

Comment: Knowing how to read and understand error messages is an important part of programming. Here we have `'str' object has no attribute 'append'`. The code is in the line above and so you can see, that you try to call `append` as a method of `user_groups[users]`. You tried to treat it as a list, but according to the error message it is a string. Now look in your code where `user_groups[users]` is defined. There is only one place, so obviously you have to change the code there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line `user_groups[users] = groups` to `user_groups[users] = [groups]`

```
# this line is creating issue because if users is not in dictionary then you are initialising that key with a string and if key is found then the value will be string and string will not support append operation thatswhy you are getting an error
```

Just edit this

```
def groups_per_user(group_dictionary):
    user_groups = {}
    for groups, user in group_dictionary.items():
        for users in user:
            if users in user_groups:
                user_groups[users].append(groups)
            else:
                user_groups[users] = [groups] 


    return(user_groups)

print(groups_per_user({"local": ["admin", "userA"],
        "public":  ["admin", "userB"],
        "administrator": ["admin"] }))
```